# planning variable not support Collect

Tags: optaplanner

i have a question,one order have many crafts, one of the crafts need two or many people to finish,so in the planning entity i usee a list object for planning variables,but when i start the application,it have a error,please give me some idea,thanks!

```
@PlanningSolution
public class ScheduleSolution extends AbstractPersistable {
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
private List<Order> orderList;
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
private List<ProductBom> productBomList;
@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
private List<JobAssignment> jobAssignmentList;
@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
@ValueRangeProvider(id = "resourceRange")
List<Resource> resourceList;
@PlanningScore
private HardSoftScore score;
}

@PlanningEntity
public class JobAssignment extends AbstractPersistable {
private ProductBom productBom;
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "resourceRange" })
private List<Resource> resourceList;
}
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entityClass (class com.demo.domain.reassign.JobAssignment) has a PlanningVariable annotated property (resourceList) that refers to a ValueRangeProvider annotated member (field java.util.List com.demo.domain.reassign.ScheduleSolution.resourceList) that returns a Collection with elements of type (class com.demo.domain.reassign.Resource) which cannot be assigned to the PlanningVariable's type (interface java.util.List). at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.valuerange.descriptor.AbstractFromPropertyValueRangeDescriptor.processValueRangeProviderAnnotation(AbstractFromPropertyValueRangeDescriptor.java:136)

Answer (score 0):

A @PlanningVariable cannot be a List, not until we support @PlanningVariableCollection some day. Possible fix:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class JobAssignment extends AbstractPersistable {
private ProductBom productBom;
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "resourceRange" })
private Resource resource;
}
```

Comment: So when annotations do not support, how do we solve the problem if Collection is needed?

Comment: Create multiple `JobAssignment` instances for the same `ProductBom`. Trouble is that you need to decide the number of resources per productBom in advance, before the solver starts. If you can't do that - it becomes more difficult - but one technique is to create a reasonable maximum number and use `nullable = true` to allow optaplanner to assign less.