# Calculating minimum required visits without predefined list

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner

I would like  to know whether the following use-case is intended to be solved with Optaplanner.

**Problem description**

[Problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4TqK.png)

There is a vehicle that needs to go from Start to End (location to location) over a mesh of nodes.
Nodes are connected with "nodeConnection" and there can be many nodeConnections between two nodes. NodeConnection also contains the price of that route.
I need a solution that tells me list of nodeConnections to take.

Number of NodeConnections that the vehicle will take is unknown. vehicle might go A - B and only take 1 NodeConnection, or go A - D and take 3 NodeConnections ( A-B connection B-C connection and then C-D connection)

**What is required**

Basically I'd like to give Optaplanner an input of 2 Nodes (locations) and a list of available NodeConnections and get back an "optimal" route for that input.
I'd like to know which route is cheapest, eg. in the provided image it's the one marked with a green line because total trip cost is 150.

**What I tried**

I thought that I could have NodeConnection collection as a @PlanningProperty, however that is currently not supported by OptaPlanner.

Then I came across [planning variable not support Collect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64467195/planning-variable-not-support-collect) and tried to have a RouteNodeConnection as a many-to-many relation between a Route and a NodeConnection, eg. 1 route would have N NodeConnections - but we do not know how much, we just want the "best" route.

The problem at the moment is "telling" OptaPlanner what we want and setting up the Constraints.

VRP repository seemed similar but there are differences:

- I only use 1 vehicle, not an entire fleet
- no need to go back to the starting point
- no need to calculate various distances since NodeConnection prices/distances are already defined

I read about chained @PlanningVariables and it seems that that approach must be taken here to create a chain of NodeConnections, however I am not sure how to setup the constraints and get OptaPlanner to actually return the best route.

Is this something that can be done with OptaPlanner or a more simpler solution might be enough here. I looked at Dijkstra's Algorithm to get the shortest path and then we'd have to figure out how to "weight" other constraints I will introduce later and so on but OptaPlanner seems more fit for this problem -  especially considering the fact that other than price, we're most likely going to have additional 5 hard and over 10 soft constraints that would be hard to "weigh" in graph algorithms.

Any tips on how to approach this problem are very welcome.

Classes for reference:

```
public class Node {
    private String Name;
}

public class NodeConnection {
    private Node StartPosition;
    private Node EndPosition;
    private BigDecimal Price;
}

public class Route {
    private Node Start;
    private Node End;
    private BigDecimal RoutePrice;
    private List<NodeConnection> NodeConnections;
}

// "Many-to-many" relation
public class RouteNodeConnection {
    private Route Route;
    private NodeConnection NodeConnection;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this looks *exactly* the same as the VRP, if you remove the "cost" of returning to the depot with 0, providing the problem with only 1 vehicle rather than several vehicles, and replacing the "distance" cost with your "nodo-to-node"- cost...

Comment: If I understand correctly, VRP goes through all the points, we want as little as possible points from A to B.

Comment: That's of no importance : OptaPlanner will rule out those combinations which "cost" more ( = *your* definition of *your* cost as implemented in *your* constraint set). On the contrary : OptaPlanner will find this out, and it is even *better* that it considers combinations that are (**at first**) seemingly less than ideal. It does this to avoid getting stuck in local optima !

OTOH, you stated : "vehicle might go A - B and ... ( A-B... C-D connection)". Of which I deduce it's not the "number" of connections you deem important, but the cost of all connections between the 2 points. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Correct, I misstyped, we're primarily interested in getting a set of connections with the lowest price.

Comment: Then your problem setting resumes into the VRP problem, adapted with the constraints in a way like I shortly stated above. **How**  OptaPlanner comes to its solution (be it with 100 connections, finding out the better solution is only 2, or 50) is of minor importance, and will be finally handled by your constraints. **How quickly** it comes to it's solution isn't, and that's where your solver configuration comes into play (I suggest you have a look at the benchmarker).
But as far as your problem is concerned : see the VRP, adapt your constraints, and let the solver do it's thing...

Comment: How would you approach modelling the PlanningSolution / PlanningEntity in this case?

Comment: Would it be correct to say that input is Node A and Node B with all possible NodeConnections between them, and desired output is a list of optimal NodeConnections.

Hard constraint: every new NodeConnection must start where previous one ends

Soft constraint: price

Comment: input : first all nodes (and the connections to their nodes - if not all nodes are connected or connectable to all connections), and secondly also all connections (connections connected to other connections - and possibly to nodes). Your constraint set : see the VRP : adapt the VRP distance "cost" to (your) node-conn.-to-conn.-node cost (all possible combinations have to have their own cost !). Then also delete the VRP's distance "cost" of returning from the last location to the depot. All the rest should be pretty much similar to the VRP, as far as I can see (if I don't forget anything)